# "This form cannot be opened in a web browser. To open this form, use MS Infopath"...why am I getting this message?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, list-form

I'm creating a simple out of the box workflow in SP2010 for a calendar.  Content Type is ALL, Approval - SharePoint 2010.  Then when I click continue.  I receive the "This form cannot be opened in a web browser.  To open this form, use MS InfoPath".  I didn't use InfoPath.  Has anyone else experienced this?  I've searched all the solutions are individuals using InfoPath.  Is there something else that's causing this?

Comment: did you used Nintex workflow or form?

Comment: @MSallal, I'm using an out of the box workflow.  However, further investigation from the customer, the customer accidently deleted the existing workflow.  Now I do see Nintex on SiteActions option so it might have been a Nintex form?

Comment: the easiest way is to install info path and open it using info, so that you can override the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the known issue in SharePoint out of the box workflow because it sends the item URL directly which only opens in the browser and there is no configuration for out of the box workflow form template.  As an alternate solution you may develop your own workflow to do the same where you can configure the template form as we need.

Here is details answers for the same issue in MSDN forum :

"
That's the problem with using the OOTB workflows. They simply send a link directly to the XML file, but that link isn't what opens the form in the browser.  The browser URL is way longer and much different, so you need to send that instead.  Since you can't modify OOTB workflows, then it's not something you can configure.  If you make your own workflow with SharePoint Designer, then you can dynamically generate the browser URL for the form so that it opens in the browser.  If you want to do that, I can show you quickly how to do it.  If you must stick with the OOTB workflow, then the forms will only open in the browser if the user does not have InfoPath 2007"

Reference URL :

[Approval Workflows with Browser-Based InfoPath Forms Not Opening In Browse](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80aa75d8-05b5-46a2-9754-1e926eebc200/approval-workflows-with-browserbased-infopath-forms-not-opening-in-browser?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)